# Unable to access the playstore console account

Tags: console, google-play, account

I am a developer. I signed up for my Play Store console account with a company email like `appdev@companyname.com` We recently publish our app on the play store console account.

Somehow our email subscription from the hosting was expired/deleted and we were not able to log in to the Gmail account using our email(`appdev@companyname.com`).

After recreating the email on hosting when login to Gmail, the same email was just like a new email for google space, and when tried to open the play console it was asking to signup, although we had already signup using the same email before and also published an app from that account. Now I need the answers to the questions below:

1. Is our app abandoned now?
2. Is there a way we can recover our account and connect back to our email (`appdev@companyname.com`)
3. If yes, we can recover the account then how?

Please check and let me know. Thanks